# Como criar uma rota Privada em React e mostrar somente se o usuário estiver autenticado através de um Token

Tags: react, react-hooks, react-router, react-dom

Estou seguindo a lógica de um video que vi da rockseat. Ao executar o programa, recebo a mensagem `[PrivateRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>`, tentei outra forma porém a rota não é renderizada.

Olhando o código, reparem que o a rota `/inicio` seria um exemplo de rota privada, mas como eu disse, não está renderizando.

**Arquivo de rotas:**

```
function App() {

  function isAuthenticated() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token') !== null;
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Main />}></Route>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
        <Route path="/nova-senha" element={<NewPassword />}></Route>
        {/* <Route path="/inicio" element={<Inicio/>}></Route> */}
        <Route path="/inicio-empresas" element={<Empresas />} />
        <Route path="/inicio-perfil" element={<PerfilPage />} />
        <Route path="/inicio-infoAuxiliares" element={<InforAuxiliares />} />
        <Route path="/inicio-testeRastreio" element={<TesteRastreio />} />
        <Route path="/inicio-usuarios" element={<Usuários />} />
        <Route path="/inicio-liberarTeste" element={<LiberarTeste />} />

        ***<Route path="/inicio" element={<PrivateRoute Component={<Inicio />} />} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />***
      </Routes>
    </Router>


  );
```

**Arquivo de rota privada**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function PrivateRoute({ element: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return <Component {...rest} />;
  } else {
    navigate('/login');
    return null;
  }
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score -2):

Utilizar a abordagem de verificar se está autenticado apenas via Token sem uma validação vinda do backend não é bom, tente utilizar essa abordagem

1. 1 - realize login  2 - salve o Token do usuário no localstorage ou
   Cookie ai você decide. 3 - Crie uma função para sempre validar o
   Token via banckend. 4 - se valido continua retorna o user logado.

**Arquivo de Rota:**

```
function App() {

  function isAuthenticated() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token') !== null;
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Main />}></Route>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
        <Route path="/inicio-empresas" element={<PrivateRoute auth={isAuthenticated}}>
                <Empresas  />
              </PrivateRoute> } />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
```

**Arquivo de Verificação:**

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, auth}:{children:JSX.Element, auth:boolean) {
  
  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return <Login />;
  } 
  

  return children;
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```